# Mongodb parallel Groupby

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to aggregate this collection where I need to find no of wins and loss of a particular team

```
 {
 "team1" :"ruby",
 "team2" :"jade",
"winner" :"ruby"
},
{
 "team1" :"jade",
 "team2" :"ruby",
 "winner" :"jade"
}
```

to

```
{
 "team" :"ruby",
 "wins" :1, 
 "loss" :1
},
{
 "team" :"jade",
 "wins" :1, 
 "loss" :1
}
```

only thing I could think of is three queries of group by like this  and combain them both by same name

```
aggregate(
            [{
                $group: {
                    _id: "$winner",
                    wins: { $sum: 1 }
                }
            }
            ])
```

is it possible to obtain wins and losses in single query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[]` brackets to map fields as arrays followed by `$unwind` & `$group` on `team` and `$cond` with `$sum` to count `wins` and `loses`.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        winner: 1,
        team: ["$team1", "$team2"]
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$team"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$team",
        wins: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{
                    $eq: ["$winner", "$team"]
                }, 1, 0]
            }
        },
        loses: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{
                    $eq: ["$winner", "$team"]
                }, 0, 1]
            }
        }
    }
})
```